# SQL Server Report Manager report showing export, refresh, data feed buttons on separate lines

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

When I view a report in Report Manager, the page is displaying `Current Page`, `Export Drop Down`, `Find|Next`, `Refresh`, and `Export to Data Feed` buttons on separate lines consuming 25% of the top of page.  These buttons should all be on one line as they are when I view the report in Data Tools.

I am running SQL Server 2012.  I cannot see a way to configure these items to one line.  There is nothing in Site Setting to configure this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is with Internet Explorer.  When I run this report in Firefox version 28, it runs perfectly.  When I run it in Internet Explorer 11, I experience the problem.

I found this on the Microsoft site.
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11

We are happy to inform that the problem was fixed in CU8 for SQL Server 2012 Sp1.
Please visit the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2917531 to get the update.

Mariusz Cichomski
Program Manager
SQL Server, Microsoft

This did not fix my issue with the toolbar.  What I finally did to fix, from Internet Explorer Tools >>> Compatibility View Settings.  I added the website for the report server.